# SQL Server Outer Join ON Conditon Losing Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

According to everything I've read, the following code:

```
SELECT v.col1,
       tab.col2 
from   view as v left outer join table as tab 
         on v.id = tab.id
         and tab.value > 'some value'
```

should preserve all the rows from the view (V), while filtering on 'tab' against 'some value'.  So if the view has 100 rows, the output should have 100 rows.

However, that doesn't seem to be happening on the version of sql server 2012 I'm using.  The added "AND" on the "ON" statement is filtering rows even though it shouldn't. I've also tried using derived tables and temporary tables and the rows keep getting dropped.

Comment: "So if the view has 100 rows, the output should have 100 rows." - Only if there is a 1-to-1 complete mapping between `view.id` and `table.id`. If there are multiple records in `table` with the same `id` value, then your query could return more records than there are in `view`, although it sounds like your problem is the opposite, that you're getting less records returned than there are in `view`?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data which exhibits the issue? I've recreated something approximating your data structure, as best I can from the detail you've given and I get the expected behaviour you describe.

Comment: Verified correct behavior same as 3N1GM4. Throwing spaghetti at the wall here: Are you sure the view returns that many rows and you are not just looking at the table and expecting the view to show it? Have you recently made changes to an underlying element of the view and need to run sp_refreshview? Is there more to the query you aren't showing that may be filtering the results? Otherwise the only way I can replicate this behavior is to use an inner join which is not what your code is doing. As @3N1GM4 said you will have to provide more detail. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If view has 100 rows you will get AT LEAST 100 rows with this query depending on the number of "tables" per view with the same id.   You may get more than 100 but you should at least get 100.

Comment: @SMM - Oddly enough, the problem, after several frustrating days, has disappeared.  The closest possible reason would be your comment about underlying elements of the view being changed.  But, there is no way for me to know for sure.  Is there a way I can flag your comment as "answered" or something?

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer which you can mark as accepted but add your comments there. That might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying my comment out to be marked as probable resolution per question asker:

Verified correct behavior same as 3N1GM4. Throwing spaghetti at the wall here:

1. Are you sure the view returns that many rows and you are not just looking at the table and expecting the view to show it?
2. **Have you recently made changes to an underlying element of the view and need to run sp_refreshview?**
3. Is there more to the query you aren't showing that may be filtering
   the results?

   Otherwise the only way I can replicate this behavior is to use an inner join which is not what your code is doing. As @3N1GM4 said you will have to provide more detail. See stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score -2):

> should preserve all the rows from the view (V), while filtering on
>   'tab' against 'some value'. So if the view has 100 rows, the output
>   should have 100 rows.

This assumption looks wrong. Please read paragraph 'Left outer join' from this article: [Join on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join)

If in right dataset you have more then one row that can be joined you can get more rows then your left dataset has.

Comment: `"When you use left join and nothing can be joined from right dataset it will join null, so by your filter tab.value > 'some value' at least this rows can be dropped."` - Is this correct? The comparison is within the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` itself, not in a `WHERE` clause, so I don't believe it should exclude any rows entirely, only cause further records from the right side to return as `NULL`?

Comment: @3N1GM4  - you have captured my problem perfectly.  The comparison is on the ON clause yet rows from the LEFT table are being dropped even though there is a match between the left and right tables.

Comment: Left join should never drop from the left table. From the wiki: The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for tables A and B always contains all rows of the "left" table (A), even if the join-condition does not find any matching row in the "right" table (B).

Comment: @3N1GM4 You are, right The comparison is within the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN can just increase null values but number of rows will be not less then left dataset. I've fixed post

Comment: @vscorp1991 no problem, I don't think your answer really answers the question though - there's probably something unusual about their data or some other factor which is causing them to get less results than they expect, but without seeing some test data (or ideally an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it's difficult to speculate what exactly is going on.

Comment: @smm - agreed, and yet that is what seems to be happening.  In this case the "left table" is a view.  Does it have to be an actual physical table for the logic to work?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Otherwise I think people would stop using views with such unexpected results. Joining should work the same with tables, views, temp tables, table variables, CTEs, etc. See my comment on your post for some other ideas.